# IOS - multiple images going slowly upward animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, core-animation

i am new to IOS programming.  what i want is i want to show multiple images and then they go  upward  continuously and then repeat again and again  in sort of a loop. how can i do this ?

i have total 8 images which i want to show like this

[image]

i don't know how can i add 8 images and then they go upward direction  verically  continuously repeating. please help me in this. if there is any tutorial related to that and then please share

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly... You want something like a carousel but scrolling verticaly ? Do you have a piece of code or something you have already done ?

Comment: @Lapinou sorry vertically go upward slowly

Comment: horizontal means side to side

Comment: vertical means up and down

Comment: sorry yeah vertically

Comment: Ok ^^, you can check this repository: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel, I already used this in one of my app, and it's very easy to use (UIScrollView). With this, you are able to make something scroll continuously using the appropriate methods and a timer for example. Just check this repo and let's see yourself ;)

Comment: thanks for your help. i checked it but its unfortunately not what i want

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it this way. If you make your step value small enough for smooth movement it will be too slow.

You want to use UIView animation. Take a look at the the method  `animateWithDuration:animations:` (and it's variations)

Your code might look like this:

```
#define K_AMOUNT_TO_MOVE

-(void)moveImages
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0
    animations: ^
    {
    for(int i=0;i<images.count;i++)
      {
        UIImageView *MyImage = images[i];
        MyImage.center = CGPointMake (MyImage.center.x, MyImage.center.y- K_AMOUNT_TO_MOVE);
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

There are variations on that basic method that take options that will auto-reverse the animation, make it repeat, change the timing to linear instead of the default ease-in, ease-out, etc. Take a look at the method `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` in the Xcode documentation.